# A href load database items onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

i'm developing a simple Content Management System that allow users to create categories and subcategories. This is the code.

```
$categories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($categories)) {
    $text = $row['text'];
    $id = $row['id'];

    echo "<li><a href='?category=$id'>$text</a></li>";

}
```

Now, all works fine as expected but i would like that when a user click on `<li>` items the system loads subcategories related to the selected category. In PHP i can't do this so i need to use JavaScript but i don't understand why. I wrote this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadSubCategories() {
        <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['category'])) {
            echo "Hello";
        }           

        ?>  
    }

</script>
```

and obviously

```
echo "<li><a href='?category=$id' onClick='javascript:loadSubCategories()'>$text</a></li>";
```

This not works because nothing appear when i click on a link. How can i solve?

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP in a .js file..?

Comment: No, the code is into a .php file.

Comment: `echo "<li><a href='?category=".$id."'>".$text."</a></li>";`

Comment: Can you prove your function gets called..?  Add a `console.log('Hello from JS')` in your function, before the PHP

Comment: use `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` instead `mysql` read this->http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: PHP is run on the server when the page is requested. JS is run on the client while the page is being viewed. Your code will simply print "Hello" in the JS code that the client recieves. It will not execute the PHP when the JS function is called, because by then all the PHP is already executed and long forgotten.

Comment: @Sathish PHP variables inside double quotes get evaluated by PHP - so no need for this.  (And yes, it is inside double quotes)  (And you have missed off the closing single quote)

Comment: @MaggsWeb, yes, it's called correcly but don't execute PHP code (i tried to insert an echo before the if). 

Sathish, my code to echo <li> works fine. I don't need your code to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pass id attribute in function call like this:

```
 echo "<li><a id="$id" onClick='javascript:loadSubCategories(this.id)'>$text</a></li>";
```

Then you can use jQuery/Ajax, try something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    function loadSubCategories(id){
        $.ajax({
            url     : Class/Method-Name,
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : form_data,
            success : function(msg){
                // Action
            }
        }),                
    }

});
```